# Rails 3.1 Support on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Does anyone know if/when heroku will support Rails 3.1?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It already does - I've been running 3.1rc's on Heroku for months now.

Are you suffering from a specific problem or just a general question?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to use their cedar stack - builtin support for rails 3.1's new asset pipeline amongst other things.

```
heroku create [APP_NAME] -s cedar
```

Answer (score 0):

Guide for deploying 3.1 apps on heroku is here - http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar

Read the 3.0 guide before that -
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3